# Should I list upcoming publications in a short story cover letter?

Tags: cover-letter

I recently published my first short story in an anthology, and have somehow managed to get another in an upcoming issue of a magazine (contract signed and everything). Finally, I no longer have a gaping hole in my cover letter where publishing history would normally go.

The first publishing credit seems pretty lonely on its own, though. Can I just go ahead and list the upcoming piece in my next cover letter, too? For example, "I have been published in X anthology and have an upcoming piece in Y magazine"? Or would that seem presumptuous?

Comment: I think you should say, "I have been published in X anthology, and I have a piece waiting for review and publication in Y magazine." If you just say, "upcoming piece in Y magazine", that will sound like your piece has been accepted and agreed to be published.

Comment: @DoubleU in case it wasn't clear - the second piece in question *was* accepted and agreed to be published. Just not in an issue that's out just yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's absolutely fine, and quite correct!

It gives the editor very helpful information -- namely, that two different venues have decided to publish your work (and, *which*, which can sometimes be a helpful indication of strengths and style).

If you know when your story is slated to see print, that's worth mentioning -- easier to confirm and check up on -- but it's not a problem if you don't have that.

At this stage of your experience, listing accomplishments is **precisely** what a cover letter is for. And having sold two stories, not just one, is absolutely an accomplishment -- so kudos, carry on, and all the best!